# Сложная выборка из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Таблица № 1 (сообщения пользователям)

```
|id|iduser|text|

 1   4      текст1
 2   16     текст2
 3   4      текст3
```

Таблица № 2 (статус прочитанного сообщения, если сообщение прочитано, то запись есть в базе

```
| id | iduser | idmessage |
  1     4           3
```

(запись в этой таблице говор что пользователь № 4 прочёл сообщение № 3 из первой таблицы)

Задача:
вывести объеденённую таблицу со статусом прочитанности

```
Таблица 3 (выводим)
|id | iduser | text | readed

 1   4      текст1    0
 2   16     текст2    0
 3   4      текст3    1
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: что вы уже пытались сделать, что сложного оказалось в реализации ? Подклеиваете по left join вторую таблицу, если ее id NULL - значит readed 0 иначе 1

Comment: Вы принципиально в своих вопросах не отмечаете правильные ответы, данные пользователями?

Comment: Всегда отмечаю правильные ответы. (стрелочка вверх), может что-то не правильно отмечаю?

Comment: Надо галочку нажимать, это там же где стрелочка, но чуть пониже и в виде галочки :) А по поводу задачи - она решается при помощи `left join`

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии нет, это голос за ответ :) там галочка напротив ответа. Когда несколько ответов в вопросе, это остальным участником помогает определить, какой ответ был наиболее верным для вас. И в дальнейшем система сайта не будет периодически поднимать вопрос наверх как нерешенный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже сказал **Mike**, используйте `left join`, чтобы не удалить те строки, которых нет в таблице со статусом прочитанного сообщения. Ваш запрос в итоге будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
select m.*,
   if(ms.id is null, 0, 1) as readed
from messages m
   left join messages_status ms on m.id = ms.message_id
```